# Continually running UIButton every minute even app is minimized

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to run UIButton every minute when app is minimized. Therefore, I wrote a scheduledTimer function to run the button every 1 minute in Appdelegate, but it doesn't work, the error shows `developeLocationHistoryButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000024ee80`. Please give me some guidance. My code is shown below.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var backgroundUpdateTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier!
    var backgroundTaskTimer: Timer! = Timer()

    func doBackgroundTask() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            self.beginBackgroundTask()
            if self.backgroundTaskTimer != nil {
                self.backgroundTaskTimer.invalidate()
                self.backgroundTaskTimer = nil
            }

            //Making the app to run in background forever by calling the API
            self.backgroundTaskTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target:self , selector: #selector(ViewController.HistoryButton(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            RunLoop.current.add(self.backgroundTaskTimer, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
            RunLoop.current.run()
            self.endBackgroundTask()
        }
    }
    func beginBackgroundTask() {
        self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "test7", expirationHandler: {
            self.endBackgroundTask()
        })
    }
    func endBackgroundTask() {
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundUpdateTask)
        self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    }
```

I added `self.doBackgroundTask()` in ApplicationDidEnterBackground, and in ApplicationWillEnterForeground, I added

```
if self.backgroundTaskTimer != nil {
        self.backgroundTaskTimer.invalidate()
        self.backgroundTaskTimer = nil
```

Comment: In addition to the answers below, why would you want to do anything with a button when your app isn't in the foreground?  The user can't see your UI so all you are going to do is waste battery (and potentially network traffic if you are updating data from the network).  The correct approach is to update your UI (and data if required) when your app returns to the foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting means that you are trying to call a method on an object that doesn’t implement it. Your problem lies in this line

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target:self , selector: #selector(ViewController.HistoryButton(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And precisely with `target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.HistoryButton(_:))` part. `self` here is the instance of `AppDelegate` and you are teling the timer to call a method named `HistoryButton(_:)` on it. But that method is defined on a objects of type `ViewController` - which is clearly stated in the selector.

To resolve your issue you can either

1. Instantiate the `ViewController` and pass it as `target` - not recommend, as this is prone to side effects.
2. Copy the method to the `AppDelegate` and update your selector argument - better, but you have repeated code and will need to update it in both places if needed.
3. Extract the method to an outside class and use it in both places (the `AppDelegate` and `ViewController`)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you are trying to do. If you request background time using  `UIApplication`'s `beginBackgroundTask(withName:expirationHandler:)` method you get 3 minutes, and after that your app will get suspended anyway. The best you'll be able to do is to have your app's timer run for 3 minutes.

There is a lot wrong with your code.

You try to add a Timer with a target of `self` and a selector of `ViewController.HistoryButton(_:)`, but:

The current class is class AppDelegate, which does not have a method called `HistoryButton(_:)`. (Also note that method names should start with lower-case letters.)

Another thing. This code:

```
var backgroundTaskTimer: Timer! = Timer()
```

Makes no sense. There's no reason to create a Timer in that code. Make it an optional and don't assign a timer to it:

```
var backgroundTaskTimer: Timer?
```

If you create a timer using `scheduledTimer()`, there's no need to then add it to the current run loop, so get rid of the lines that begins `Runloop.current`... and the line `RunLoop.current.run()`

Another thing: Why do you call `self.endBackgroundTask()` immediately after beginning your background task?

There are other things wrong with your code, but that's a start. It's fundamentally flawed. You're trying to tackle things you clearly don't fully grasp yet. I suggest slowing down and learning the things you're trying to do bit by bit.

Comment: Thank you for your responding, it is really helpful.